# Assignments of vector: Static versus Dynamic

Tags: c, arrays, allocation

I am writing some C code here, and I came across a problem:

I have an array of my custom type. I want to put a size for this array:

```
typedef struct reg Reg;
Reg myArray[958279];
```

When I run my program has a segmentation fault.

Then I tried using malloc, which allocates storage space dynamically, and to my surprise it worked:

```
Reg *myArray = (Reg*)malloc(sizeof(Reg)*958279);
```

So I assumed there must be some size restriction for array declaration of a static form.

Is there any reference to this fact somewhere? Or am I completely wrong about the my questions?

Comment: The first is a stack allocation, the second is a heap allocation. Stack allocations are very fast, but the stack has a finite size for each thread (8 MB on my system, but I've seen it as low as 512 KB).

Comment: Do you know any reference to this fact in the documentation of the C language?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: How do you know that? For all I can tell, the first one could be static allocation... :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB And smart-asses like you are the reason I made that a comment instead of an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array in your first piece of code is, presumably, being allocated on the stack and does not fit. The stack typically has a fixed size and you must not allocate huge objects on the stack. The solution, as you have discovered, is to allocate from the heap.

Comment: Do you know any reference to this fact in the documentation of the C language?

Comment: The C standard doesn't say anything on the subject. For example there is no minimum amount of stack space that a conforming C implementation must provide. That part of the system is always implementation specific. On most systems, the amount of stack allocated/reserved for a thread can be controlled by the program/compiler. But don't think that it's a good idea to make your stack huge. That can come back to bite you later on. Usually it makes good sense to stick with the system default stack size.

Comment: Alternatively you could give the array static storage duration (= make it global), which may even be faster.

Comment: @kerrek why would it be faster? Unlikely that a single allocation during the lifetime of a process would dominate perf. Usually semantics determines storage decisions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Depends. If the OP is using the construction in a loop, he might be allocating the space repeatedly. It's just an idea. Also, static storage gives you a better guarantee that you can actually obtain the space (you'd fail at load time if not).